# How to create a new branch in new location as continuation from other branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a git repo with branch parent_branch with some commits in /temp/project/.
Now I have a new local folder /temp/other_folder/project/ with some files which I need to push to the same above repo with new branch child_branch that emerged from above parent_branch.

One brute-force way I can do it is to clone the git repo with parent_branch checkout at some temp location and then remove all the files except .git and move all the files from new local folder there and then do

```
git checkout -b child_branch
git add and commit and push
```

But I want to do it without moving files here and there and do it with git bash from the new local location /temp/other_folder/project/ only.

```
# /temp/other_folder/project/
git init
git add remote origin <git_url>
somehow create a child_branch from the parent branch
 A -> B -> c ... parent_branch
       \-> D ... child_branch
git add and commit and push to origin/child_branch
```

Comment: have you heard [fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo)..? you can fork (create a copy) of a repository and enable something like [fork sync](https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork) (automatically copies update from the fork source to yours) and then create a new branch based on branches the original repo had that copied to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like *multiple worktrees* might be the thing for you.

From the [documentation of `git-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree):

> A git repository can support multiple working trees, allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time.

In this case, you could create a separate worktree in a subdirectory of your repo and associate it with the new `child_branch` branch:

```
git worktree add -b child_branch ./subdirectory parent_branch
```

This will checkout the `parent_branch` in the specified `subdirectory` and associate it with the new `child_branch` branch.

At this point, you can simply copy your new files into the subdirectory without having to clone the entire repository into a new location.

You might want to read up on how to manage multiple worktrees in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Comment: I can't move the files here as some processing is done on the parent repo here. I want to do it without copying the files anywhere.